# How do I get my link_to to go to my show method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing, link-to

I’m using Rails 5.  I’m having trouble linking to a show method in my controller.  I have this defined in my config/routes

```
  resources :scenarios do
    resources :confidential_memos
  end
```

and in a view, I put this

```
<td><%= link_to "#{subscription.scenario.title}", scenarios_path(subscription.scenario) %>
```

in my controller I have the show method

```
class ScenariosController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @scenario = Scenario.find(params[:id])
  end
```

but when I click on the link, I get the error

```
The action 'index' could not be found for ScenariosController
```

How do I get my link to get to my show action?

Comment: try scenario_path (singular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scenarios_path` uses the plural "scenarios" so it is looking for several scenarios and that maps to the `index` action, hence your error. To show a single scenario you'd use the singular:

```
scenario_path(subscription.scenario)
```

If you only have a `show` action then you might want to be explicit in your routes:

```
resources :scenarios, :only => %i[ show ] do
  #...
end
```

so that you catch the error sooner.

You could solve this yourself by doing a `rake routes` and looking for the show action that you're interested in.